# str doesn't have append attribute error

Tags: python, loops, error-handling

I have a file similar to:

```
1 a  
1 a  
1 b  
3 s  
3 p  
3 s  
3 y  
5 b  
...
```

I'm making it into a dictionary where key is column 0 and value is column 1. I'm using a loop so when I see the key **again**, I append the new value *if* the new value is not in the existing key, hence my dictionary would look like:

test_dict = {'1': [1,b], '3': [s,p,y]...}

My code looks like:

```
test_dict = {}  
with open('file.txt') as f:  
        for line in f:  
                column = line.split()  
                if column[0] not in test_dict:  
                        test_dict[column[0]] = column[3]  
                elif column[3] not in test_dict[column[0]]:  
                        test_dict[column[0]].append(column[3])  
                else:  
                        break
```

and I'm getting a `str has no attribute append error` on the append line. I know that the columns are treated as a string, how can I correct this in my code?

Comment: I think you want to be using a `list` rather than a `str` as the values of your `dict`.

Comment: Also, look in to `defaultdict`.

Comment: Your example result dictionary isn't a dictionary. Or anything, really.

Comment: The `break` case looks superfluous to me as well.

Comment: sorry about that, here it is fixed

Answer (score 3):

You can't append to a string.  You either want to do `+=` or to make the elements of `test_dict` lists.  You could also make the dict values `set`s and get rid of you duplicate checking all together, though your lists would no longer be sorted by first occurance order.

```
from collections import defaultdict

test_dict = defaultdict(set)
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        columns = line.split()
        test_dict[columns[0]].add(columns[3])
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, what is the "collections" you use there?

Comment: in fact, what does the first line do exactly?

Comment: `collections` is a built in library of various datastructures that represent collections of data in different ways.  `defaultdict` is a dictionary that automatically populates any key that doesn't yet exist with the result of calling the initializer passed.

Comment: `import` is a way of including code from other modules and packages in to your code without copy-pasting it in.  It's a pretty fundemental part of any non-trivial code.

Comment: perfect, thank you so much for the explaination, I really wanted to learn something from this. If only I had the reputation to vote up haha...

Answer (score 1):

`column[3]` is a string, `test_dict[column[0]]` will be a string. Did you mean to make it a list?

```
test_dict[column[0]] = [column[3]]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, where would I insert this? Im assuming that I will use += instead of the append, like this?

Comment: judge_list[col[0]]=+col[3]

Comment: If they're lists, you can keep the `.append()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve a similar result using [groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) followed by using [set](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to remove duplicates

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> {k: list(set(e for _,e in v))
        for k,v in groupby((e.split() for e in foo),
               key = itemgetter(0))}
{'1': ['a', 'b'], '3': ['y', 'p', 's'], '5': ['b']}
```